# Image sequence processing ConvLSTM vs LSTM architecture in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I need to train a sequence based segmentation of 10x10 images. Following are the lstm and convlstm models that I want to use:

```
def lstmModel():
    # Model definition
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, batch_input_shape=(1, None, inp.shape[1]*inp.shape[2]), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(out.shape[1]*out.shape[2], activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model


def convlstmModel():
    # Model definition
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ConvLSTM2D(12, kernel_size=5, padding = "same", batch_input_shape=(1, None, inp.shape[1], inp.shape[2], 1), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
    model.add(Conv2D(20, 3, padding='same', activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

I train the models for sequence of 10 random 10x10 image sequences. LSTM model seems to work fine for me, but ConvLSTM model shows dimension mismatch for the Conv2D layer:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LSTM` layers are meant for "time sequences".
`Conv` layers are meant for "still images".

One requires shapes like `(batch, steps, features)`
The other requires: `(batch, witdh, height, features)`

Now, `ConvLSTM2D` mixes both and requires `(batch, steps, width, height, features)`

When leaving the `ConvLSTM2D` you have an extra `steps` dimension not supported by the `Conv2D`.

If you want to keep this dimension, use the convolution with a `TimeDistributed` wrapper:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...))
```

Notice that you will still have all 5 dimensions, in contranst with your other model that has only 3.

You should use some kind of reshape or other operations to make it suitable to your training data.

Since your question doesn't show anything about it, that's all we can answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is implying that your input data is coming to the conv2d layer with 5 dimensions rather than 4. The model should receive an input shaped like

```
(samples, time, rows, cols, channels)
```

given that you are using a channels-last backend (tensorflow). Then, each slice of `(time,rows,cols,channels)` is sent through the conv2d layer one by one. However, the error message is implying the passed dimension is 5 rather than the expected 4. Verify the shape of your input data and the answer can be modified if necessary.